# Disable Control's Selection Background Effect in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, isenabled

I have a ListView which shows a collection of objects. I want to disable the "Blue effect" or "Blue rectangle" when clicking on the ListViewItem, and Let only the object in this Item enabled. Does anyone has an idea about that ??

Here is an Example of one of my ListViewItems:

[image: LisViewItem]

Here is my listView:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" IsManipulationEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildrenList}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
        <ListView.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding IsVertical, Converter={StaticResource AngleOfBool}}"></RotateTransform>
        </ListView.LayoutTransform>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox   Content="{Binding Id}"  Height="auto" Name="Flag" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <area:Area HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You'll have to modify the control template.

Comment: How, can you explain more please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `IsEnabled` property of a parent control to `False` will automatically set the `IsEnabled` property of every child control to `False` as well. The only way around this is to set the `IsEnabled` property of the individual controls that you want to be disabled to `False`, *instead* of that of the parent control.

However, you can create one `bool` property to `Bind` to the `IsEnabled` property of all of the relevant controls so that at least, you can disable and enable them all using the one property:

```
<Grid Name="Parent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl IsEnabled="AreInnerControlsEnabled" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter= {StaticResource VisibilityOfBool} }"></ContentControl>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter= {StaticResource VisibilityOfBool} }" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label IsEnabled="AreInnerControlsEnabled" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" Content="{Binding Top}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" Content="{Binding Bottom}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Using this method, only the controls using the `AreInnerControlsEnabled` property will be affected.

UPDATE >>>

So it turns out that you actually want to remove the default selection colour of the `ListView`... that is very different to what you 'appeared' to be asking. However, now I know that, you can achieve that very easily by using a simple `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="HiddenDefaultSelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

You only need one of these to hide that colour, but I have shown you the rest for future reference. You can use it like this:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HiddenDefaultSelectionStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: I'm Sorry @Sheridan ! I think I put the wrong ListView, I Updated the post! The problem is : As you can see in the Image I put as Example, I don't want that the "Blue filling" will appear after clicking on the listeViewItem. So I tried "IsEnabled = False ", But the CheckBox was disabled too ! How to do ??

Comment: Oh, are you talking about the default `Background` selection colour (of the selected item)?

Answer (score 1):

As I stated at the comments, I would change the ListViewItem template.
The code is very verbose, so let's do it:

First, create a ResourceDictionary and set a reference to it in you `App.xaml`.
Having done that, paste the code below at the ResourceDictionary:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Notice that the first 6 tags (`SolidColorBrush`) have the references to the colors according to the state of the ListViewItem.
From here, you can take 2 paths, change the `SolidColorBrush` Color to whatever you want to, in your case `Transparent` OR remove the `Triggers` altogether (not recommended).

When you're done, set the `Style` property of your ListBoxItem to the `x:Key` you named. In the code the name is `x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1"`.

I hope that this guide you!

Comment: Thank you very much @Tico, This code is the really helpfull to manage all the effects of the control !

Comment: WPF is extremely customizable, I love it! Too bad I didn' get the answer!

Comment: I hope that I can give you the answer too ! because your job is also great ! Hope you'll be here if I'll need help again ! Thanks