# Remove strange behaviour from wpf button mouse-over

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, styles, mouseover

I'm fighting with a dummy issue for hours.

In wpf I want to override the behaviour of a `Button`, and at the moment the basic behaviour I want is reached (a certain color).

But I'm not able to say simply: on mouseover add underline style!
I'm able to add underline but I'm not able to remove the square around the text!

[image: This is before the mouseOver: ok]

[image: The underline is ok but why the light-blue square around the text!?!]

The style I'm using is:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vs_shell:EnvironmentColors.CommandBarMenuLinkTextBrushKey}}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Background="Transparent"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Any idea/suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you :

[Disable Control's Selection Background Effect in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221538/disable-controls-selection-background-effect-in-wpf)

It concerns the ListViewItems, but you can apply this mechanism on buttons or any other WPF Controls.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add this setter to the style:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```